# Mysql Query With Php To Match Keywords And Rank According To Most Match

Tags: php, mysql, sql

tbl index.tbl that looks like this with entries:

```
id | Url                    | Description
0  | http://cheapnames.it   | Register Domain Names from $1 to $25.
1  | http://lownames.usa    | Get Domain Names from $1 to $20.
2  | http://lowcostnames.uk | Register Domains for as low as $1.
3  | http://getdoman.biz    | Register Names from between $1 to $25.
```

Now, imagine you did a search for "register domain names".

I want the query to rank the rows based on the most matched keywords (number of matches). So, from our example, the ranking should be like this:

```
0| http://cheapnames.it   | Register Domain Names from $1 to $25.
1| http://lownames.usa    | Get Domain Names from $1 to $20.
3| http://getdoman.biz    | Register Names from between $1 to $25.
2| http://lowcostnames.uk | Register Domains for as low as $1.
```

- Note that, the id=0 has 3 KWs matches. Hence on top.
- Both the id=1 & id=3 have 2 matches. Hence 2nd & 3rd. Amongst these 2, priority of rank is given based on "id" (link submission id).
- And of course, the last matched row is at the bottom.

Questions:

1. How would you write the Sql query be doing the querying & ranking like I described ?
2. Is just the Sql querying enough here to do the ranking display like described or have to get php to do the ranking display as well? Or, maybe Sql should not be doing the ranking display at all but php? In that case, may I see a php sample code?

This no good which I got so far:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM notices WHERE description = register AND Domain AND 
Names";
```

Kindly show code samples as my sample ain't working regarding the "most matching ranking".

3. Bearing in mind that the link description would be limited like you see in search engine result pages (SERPs), should I choose VARCHAR(255) or  TinyText or Text or FullText in mysql as column type?

Comment: You are looking a [Full Text Searching](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-search.html) based solutions.

Comment: I've had some pretty good experience using [Full text search in boolean mode](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-boolean.html) with MySQL try looking into that.

Comment: I've entered your phrase into Google as well "I want the query to rank the rows based on the most matched keywords (number of matches)." with `mysql` added to it. And Fulltext search pop up on the search results.

Comment: ... or Solr ... or Elasticsearch ... depends on scale really.

Comment: Rimble,From your link,you suggest I use this format: '+apple +(>turnover <strudel)' ? Yes ?